# Matrikon OPC server and ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, opc

I have problem with asp.net mvc application and OPC server from Matrikon. I use H.Opc library (from nuget package menager) I used Tutorial from http://mestaa.blogspot.com http://mestaa.blogspot.com/2010/11/opc-client-c-net-sample-rslinx-opc.html With this code my winforms applications works correctly. In my asp.net mvc application I placed calling the connection with OPC server in global.asax file. This is static class, in this class I have methots to connect, send and receive data. In debug mode (in visual studio) I can run application, I have access to OPC, I can send and receive data between my web application and opc, it seems to be everything ok.

But I have problem in destrination paltform (local IIS on the same PC), I cannot run my aplication due to problems with Matrikon OPC server. My application is not albe to run. Aplication returns error

```
row 28:             server.Connect(url, new Opc.ConnectData(new System.Net.NetworkCredential()));
row 29: 
row 30:             groupState = new Opc.Da.SubscriptionState();
row 31:             groupState.Name = "GroupRead";
row 32:             groupState.UpdateRate = 100;

Source file: C:\Users\mns\Desktop\WFDViewer\WFDViewer\Infrastructure\PLC.cs    row: 30 


[ExternalException (0x80004005): CoCreateInstanceEx: server execution failed.
]
   Opc.Server.Connect(URL url, ConnectData connectData) +390
   Opc.Da.Server.Connect(URL url, ConnectData connectData) +37
   WFDViewer.Infrastructure.PLC.ConnectToPLC() in C:\Users\mns\Desktop\WFDViewer\WFDViewer\Infrastructure\PLC.cs:30
   WFDViewer.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\Users\mns\Desktop\WFDViewer\WFDViewer\Global.asax.cs:27

[HttpException (0x80004005): CoCreateInstanceEx: server execution failed.
]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +540
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +186
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +402
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +343

[HttpException (0x80004005): CoCreateInstanceEx: server execution failed.
]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +539
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +125
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +731
```

I tried to change levels of permissions in DCOM configuration, but in spite of change I an not able run my asp.net mcv application on production platform.

Did someone meet the same problem ?

Comment: Does IIS_IUSRs have rights to DCOM?  I am not sure this is the fix, but I have run into issues when it didn't have rights to directories I was working with, maybe this is a similar issue?

Comment: Yes, I added rights to DCOM for IIS_IUSR user.  The application requires rights to wwwroot directories and it seems to be ok, when I remove PLC.Connect() from global.asax file the application runs and works correctly, but I do not have data coming from PLC.

Comment: I wonder how you could troubleshoot that?  It seems that the issue is ASP.Net calling the DCOM, so I wonder if DCOM is being called from a credential we are not expecting.  So something other than IIS_IUSRS or what ever you have set in the application pool.  Wish I had a device to be more helpful.  Good luck in finding a solution!